# Fetched data using fetch API not showing on networked devices

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

Currently I'm learning react, and I'm the part of using fetch api, I was able fetch the data and display data on my local computer, but when in preview on my mobile which is connected to the same network is just showing data that were not fetched, what should I do inorder to view the fetched data?

I tried to add the port of the fetched url in my network firewall inbound rules, but still the fetched data is not showing.
Below is my code for my fetch api:

```
useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/destinations')
        .then(res => {
        if(!res.ok){        //error throwing
            throw Error('could not fetch the data for that resource');
          }
          return  res.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
           console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            
            console.log(err.message);
        })
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can open Command Prompt and type `ipconfig`. Look for the IPv4 Address under your active network connection.
On Mac or Linux, use Terminal and type `ifconfig` or `ip addr show` and look for the IPv4 address.

**Replace `localhost` with your IP address in the fetch request:**

```
useEffect(() => {
fetch('http://YOUR_COMPUTER_IP:8000/destinations')
    .then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw Error('could not fetch the data for that resource');
        }
        return res.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        // Update state or do something with the fetched data here
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.message);
    })
}, []);
```

Comment: already tried that, its not working,

Answer (score 0):

Already solved, I put my json inside public folder, and called in fetch as local file

```
useEffect(() => {
fetch('data.json')
    .then()
})
```

Comment: this is not a good idea. 
that useEffect will be called on every change of state and will fetch again. even if you are learning, that is a bad practice and you should not stick to it.

Comment: oh ok, thanks for the tip, but can i use fetch event without useEffect?

Comment: you can at the first render of the screen by adding an empty array as dependency to the useEffect
`useEffect(() => {}, [])` and that way this useEffect will be called only at the initial render of the screen/component

Comment: wow thanks, it was mentioned in the module but i think i kinda missed it, that help the rerenders haha, thanks alot